# Sending lxml etree as svg in a Response

Tags: python, flask, svg, lxml

I am trying to read svg file in an etree

```
tree = etree.parse(open(svgFilePath, 'r'))
```

And doing some manipulations on the `tree`. Now I want to return it as a svg whenever a user posts a request. I can't find a way to return it back as the svg(after the manipulations) without saving the svg on my localhost.

I am using fastapi as the framework.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for a bit, I came up with the following solution.

```
root = tree.getroot()
svg = etree.tostring(root,pretty_print=True)
return Response(content=svg, media_type="application/svg+xml")
```

Now I can see the svg as a Response.

I used postman for visualization.